# BindException multiplethread server

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, exception, binding

I have 3 server and I run following code in these servers. However one of them gives rror:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.BindException: Address already in use
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.bind(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at MultiThreadServer.main(MultiThreadServer.java:22)
```

Even I stop running the program with command "ps -ef | grep java | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill -9", it still gives same exception.
The code is below:

```
public class MultiThreadServer implements Runnable {
Socket csocket;
MultiThreadServer(Socket csocket) {
    this.csocket = csocket;
}

public static void main(String args[]) 
        throws Exception {
    ServerSocket ssock = new ServerSocket(8879);
    System.out.println("Listening");
    while (true) {
        Socket sock = ssock.accept();
        System.out.println("Connected");
        new Thread(new MultiThreadServer(sock)).start();
    }

}
public void run() {..}
```

Comment: Because a port cannot be used by multiple programs and it may take some time for the OS to clean up after the program was closed (especially if it crashed)

Comment: If it is correct, how does it work in other two server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The port is probably already in use. Try using a different port.